# Deploy a Project in Eclipse with Gradle to a device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a project in Eclipse with gradlle.
I want to run the project on a physica device, but I do not see the option.

I select run tab, project just runs gradle.

Check below `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {   
     compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile files ('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar')
     compile files ('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
     compile files ('libs/agilio_rtmp-debug.jar')
     compile files ('libs/facebook-android-sdk-4.14.1.jar')
     compile files ('libs/agilio_rtmp-debug.jar')
}
```

When I select run:
[image]

Comment: Gradle has an `app:installDebug` task. Do you not see it?

Comment: I do not see it.  where is it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your Gradle files.

Comment: I just edit my question

Comment: Did you write that by hand? You've applied the Java plugin, so there won't be any android tasks. Feel free to read up on Android and Gradle.  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Comment: i see that on picture there is `Gradle tasks`. write there  `build installDebug`. It should after click `Run`, execute these tasks

Comment: @piotrek1543 The `com.android.application` plugin is not applied. That task won't exist

Comment: @kaka change `apply plugin 'java'` to `apply plugin 'com.android.application'`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run the project on a physical device.

The task you want is `app:installDebug`, but that is assuming you have the correct project structure.

---

Since it isn't clear what the structure your project has, here is the recommended structure from the [Android Gradle documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html).

```
settings.gradle
build.gradle            # Top-level
app/                    # A module named 'app'
  build.gradle          # Module-level
  libs/
    library-1.jar
    library-2.jar
    ...
  src/main/
    AndroidManifest.xml
    java/               # application package in here, then Java files in that
    res/
```

This is the `settings.gradle`

```
include ':app'
```

Here is a **top-level** `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
}
```

Then, the **module** `build.gradle` with adjustments for your dependencies.

Most importantly - The top line here tells Gradle this is an android app, not a java app. This means you can run the various Android-related Gradle tasks like `installDebug`, which is the one you are looking for.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    // Variables to keep libraries consistent
    supportLibrary = '23+'

    // Support Libraries dependencies
    supportDependencies = [
            design           :         "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrary}",
            appCompatV7      :         "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibrary}"
    ]

}

dependencies {
     compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

     // This line already compiles all jar files in the libs/ directory
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // recommended
    compile supportDependencies.design
}
```